# Conversão de letra para minúscula dá um resultado numérico

Tags: c++, string, conversão

Em qual parte desse código em C++ estou errando em que necessito converter uma palavra toda para minúsculo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>


using namespace std;

int main(){

   string nome = "Pedro";

   int tam = nome.size();

   int i;

        for(i = 0 ; i < tam ; i++){
            cout << tolower(nome[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Além do código desorganizado precisa [dizer que quer uma letra e não um número](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) porque segundo a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) é isso que a função `tolower()` resulta por padrão.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nome = "Pedro";
    int tam = nome.size();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < tam ; i++) cout << tolower(nome[i], locale());
}
```

Mas se quiser usar C++ moderno:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (auto letra : "Pedro") cout << tolower(letra, locale());
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aWGDs7). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/errbamip-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/ToLower.cpp).